# Are these valid subspaces?

Tags: linear-algebra

for my math class, we have a problem set and the following question appeared.

Let $P_3 = \{p(t) = a+bt+ct^2+dt^3\}$ be the vector space of polynomials of degree of at most 3. Determine which (if any) of the following subsets are subspaces.

1. $p(t) = a+bt+ct^2+dt^3$ with $a = 0$.
2. $p(t) = a+bt+ct^2+dt^3$ with $a + b + c + d= 0$.
3. $p(t) = a+bt+ct^2+dt^3$ with $a, b, c, d$ integers.
4. $p(t) = a+bt$ with $a + 2b = 0$.

For the first one, I said that it is not a valid subspace, because it is not closed under addition. Now, this is where I am stuck. If that is the case (I understand it may not be), wouldn't all of them not be subspaces?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: What makes you say the first one isn't closed under addition?  If you have a $p_1(t)=a_1+b_1t+c_1t^2+d_1t^3$ and you have a $p_2(t)=a_2+b_2t+c_2t^2+d_2t^3$, then what is $p_1(t)+p_2(t)$?  What is the constant term?  Since $a_1=0$ and $a_2=0$ what is $a_1+a_2$?

Comment: Alright, I thought that because I thought we were defining addition as p(x) + p(y), which would not be equal to p(x+y), because, for example, cx^2 + cy^2 is not equal to c(x+y)^2. I understand that would be closed under addition now.

Comment: Also to check:  the zero vector is an element of the subspace (*the zero polynomial in this case*) and that it is closed under scalar multiplication (presumably the scalar field in this question is $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$).  In general, one could check all properties simultaneously by seeing if for any $p_1(t)$ and $p_2(t)$ and scalar $\alpha$ that $\alpha p_1(t)+p_2(t)$ is also an element.  Remember that addition is component-wise.  The parent vector space here is isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^4$.

Comment: So, the first would be a valid subspace correct?

Comment: I'll let you figure that out, but you seem to be on the right track.  From what I see exactly one is not a subspace and the other three are.  Presumably your work needs to be shown for full credit so it remains to be proven using the properties given.

Answer (score 0):

Note that 1,2 &4 can be written as
$S_\alpha = \{ p | p(\alpha) = 0 \}$ for some fixed $\alpha$.

The map $L_\alpha:P_3 \to \mathbb{R}$ defined by $Lp = p(\alpha)$ is linear and
$S_\alpha = \ker L_\alpha$.

Since the kernel of a linear operator is a subspace, it follows that the $S_\alpha$ are subspaces.

For the third, consider a non zero polynomial $p$ with integer coefficients.
Is $\sqrt{2} p$ a member of this set?